# Enviar formulário sem refresh e trazer resultados para a mesma página

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Preciso enviar um formulário do tipo POST para fazer uma consulta em uma página PHP *(painel-admin.php)* e retornar os resultados dessa consulta, nessa mesma página do form (**sem refresh**), como poderia fazer?

> Imagino que vou ter que usar Ajax, mas, não sei como...

O código que eu tenho, está funcionando, utilizei `SESSION`, porém, está dando refresh na página.

**HTML:** (painel-admin.php)

```
    <form method="post" action="verificar-painel-admin.php">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" value="joaozinho" readonly>
        <button type="submit" name="confirm_usuario_pedido">Clique aqui para consultar os pedidos desse usuário.</button>
    </form>
        
        <p> 
            <div class="card-deck">
                <?php
                    // Exibindo os pedidos do cliente caso haja.
                    if(isset($_SESSION['msg_pedidos_usuario'])){
                    echo $_SESSION['msg_pedidos_usuario']; 
                    unset($_SESSION['msg_pedidos_usuario']);}
                ?>
            </div>
        </p>
```

**PHP:** (verificar-painel-admin.php)

```
 if(isset($_POST['confirm_usuario_pedido'])){
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];

    // Todos os pedidos do usuário 
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID_compras FROM usuarios_pedidos WHERE usuario = '$cliente'");
    $qnt_pedidos = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

        // Se existir pedido desse usuário, exibir.
        if ($qnt_pedidos > 0) {

            while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

            $_SESSION['msg_pedidos_usuario'] = "Você possui ". $qnt_pedidos . "pedidos";

            }  } // End IF & While 

        else{
             $_SESSION['msg_pedidos_usuario'] = "<h4>Você ainda não possui pedidos!</h4>"; 
        } 

    header("Location: painel-admin.php");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, sim você vai ter que usar AJAX para tal tarefa. Vi que você botou jquery, então vou utilizá-lo neste exemplo.

Como você não exibiu sua página de formulário, vou falar o que eu acho que deve ser feito.

- PHP:

1. Crie um arquivo para lidar com esse backend: `seu_arquivo.php`
2. Configure o arquivo, e tratativas para impedir que usuários acessem esse arquivo diretamente do navegador (eu costumo enviar post por ajax, e faço um `if(!$_POST){ header('location: ...') }`)
3. Uma vez que você fez todo o insert do seu formulário, você vai ter que fazer um select para ter esses dados prontos para exibição(um jeito interessante é o [PDO::lastInsertId()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php)),
4. Com os dados prontos, você pode optar por gerar um json com esses dados ou já exibir em HTML, dentro de tags e tals (em json é o jeito mais atual), e depois desse `echo` com os dados, sair do arquivo.

- Javascript

1. Enviar o formulário para o backend por ajax. Como você disse que não sabe como, vou fazer um exemplo:

   ```
   var dados = $('seu_formulario').serialize() // serialize() pega todos os valores dos inputs filhos do formulario no seletor

   // função post(), vai fazer a requisição ajax
   // primeiro parametro é a url,
   // segundo é referente aos dados do seu form a serem enviados, 
   // terceiro é como vc vai lidar com o retorno
   $.post(
       'seu_arquivo.php',
       dados,
       function(respostaAjax){
           // aqui que vai rolar a exibição, é interessante fazer uma validação antes,
           // voce pode dar um echo 'ERRO' no php e ler esse erro aqui, e exibir pro usuario
           if(respostaAjax == 'ERRO') {
               alert('ERRO blabla...'); // sua tratativa de erro

           } else {
               // vamos supor que você resolveu dar echo no html pronto
               $('sua_div').html(respostaAjax) // pronto, sua div vai ter os dados do backend sem nenhum refresh
               // se você resolveu fazer com json, pode dar um JSON.parse(respostaAjax) e então ir modificando
           }
       }
   ```

De forma bem resumida, é isso, se tiver alguma dúvida, to a disposição, espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! mas infelizmente sou leigo com `ajax, json, etc...`, não sei muito bem como fazer. Se não for pedir muito, não teria como você dar exemplos mais detalhados se baseando em meu código? Desde como eu envio os dados do `form`, até a recuperação do mesmo?

Comment: Sem problemas, tem como sim, mas tem como a gente falar por um chat? pq provavelmente vai ser bem extenso

Comment: Acho que não tenho pontuação suficiente

Comment: E eu não sei fazer kkkk tem meu linkedin no meu perfil, me manda mensagem lá e a gente tenta ver isso ai

Comment: Boa Resposta, existem também outras bibliotecas como Axios ou você pode chamar de forma nativa com XMLHttpRequest ou com a novo fetch().